# How to mirror objects without using modifier

Tags: transforms

I have seen in some tutorial but I cannot remember which one it is, that its possible to move objects close to each other and farther away from them without the mirror modifier but using the mesh symmetry. I'm trying to do it, but with no success, can someone please tell me how it's done.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For meshes I don't see any other solution than the symmetry option, but you need to make sure that the meshes are symmetrical so maybe first *Mesh > Symmetrize*, then move the right or the left cube and the other one will mirror the movement:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the video you show he is not in *Edit* mode but in *Object* mode, with 2 objects, he has enabled the *Affect Only Locations* option, and then he scales. Make sure that the *Transform Pivot Point* is not set to *Individual Origins*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found the video, not sure if it's the same, but it's helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMBMHSca_j0

the method starts at: 01:00:54 - #67 Change Distance of Objects

Comment: I've edited, what he shows in this video is not 2 meshes within one object but 2 objects